# Unique issue with id attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, dom

On this page http://stage.directsight.co.uk/detail/U5 the form on the right(the one with radio buttons) seems to have a unique issue. using jquery, its id attribute comes out to be, a node list.

this seems to be related to this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214574

Is there a fix for this? This happens on FireFox.

```
$('form').eq(1).attr('id')
```

Comment: Based on the bug report it is caused only if a form contains an element called item, so if you rename the element called item in your form it should go away. And IDs must all be different, the name attribute for radio button is what is suppose to match.

Comment: The problem happens because your radio buttons are named `id`, and according to the bug, that clobbers the form's existing property named `id`. Your options appear to be limited - give the radio buttons some different `name` attribute and update the form submission handling code to match.

Comment: getAttribute should return the attribute value, no? I am aware that doing document.form.id will give the dom node with name = "id" but form.attr('id') should return the attribute. Am I wrong in my concept?

Comment: I stand corrected - `getAttribute` does seem to work correctly. But I still think using such generic names is not a good idea.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `$('form').eq(1).attr('id') // undefined`. I don't understand what your problem is.